# Time based javascript functions with setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I'm using node.js but this question is strictly javascript related. I'm interfacing with an i2c board to fade lights and I'd like to fade them at a specific rate, say 1 second. Now with setInterval, in theory it should work like... if I wanted to fade them 100 steps in 1 second I could just do something like...

```
var fader = setInterval(function(){
//will fade light 100 steps in 1 second
    doFade(something,something);
},10)
```

But depending on the code inside of the Interval loop, it may take longer than 1 second (I tested and for my application was about 2.5 seconds). I'm sure the fact that function doFade is taking a set amount of time to happen is causing this issue but I'm just curious if there is any real way to make this actually all happen within 1 second.

Comment: how does `doFade` function look like?

Comment: Instead of assuming that the time interval is a constant 1/100th of a second, check the clock on each iteration and see how far along you actually are.

Comment: @jimmyweb it's basically a communication with a device on i2c protocol. it Does 6 Calculations, hits 2 other functions the writes 4 bytes to the i2c device.

Comment: @Pointy I thought about this, but if there's inconsistency then it would be off wouldn't it? Basically what I'm saying is, I don't think I can find that golden number

Comment: @GThompson you don't have to *find* the number. You check the clock and determine what the actually reality is. You remember when the process starts, so then on any iteration you can check the clock and determine how far along the process should be.

Comment: What about changing the number of steps? Like say 24 steps since the human eye will interpret that 24 frames per second as motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you'll ever get, AFAIK, relying entirely on JS would be to do something like this:

```
var fader = (function(now)
{
    var timeLeft, end = now + 1000,//aim for 1000 ms
        stepsRemaining = 100,
        callBack = function()
        {//define here, avoid redefining function objects
            doSomething(foo, bar);
            setter();
        },
        setter = function()
        {//recompute interval, set anew
            if (stepsRemaining <= 0)
            {//avoid infinite timeouts
                return;
            }
            timeLeft = (end - (+(new Date)));
            timeLeft= timeLeft > 0 ? timeLeft : 0;//ensure positive timeleft, if not, 0 intervals ==> ASAP
            fader = setInterval(
                callback,
                Math.floor(
                    timeLeft/stepsRemaining--
                )
            );
        };
    setter();
    return fader;
}(+(new Date)));//get ms now
```

This code, though untested creates all function objects beforehand. Then, using `setter`, everytime the interval finishes, as long as you haven't set 100 intervals, the new interval will be computed. After the work is done, by the `callBack` function, `setter` is called again. Here, the number of remaining steps is checked, then the timeLeft is computed again and based on the remaining steps, which are decremented by 1 on each call to `setter`.
To avoid setting the intervals too long, or using float-numbers, I'm calling `Math.floor`, and to avoid setting negative timeout values, I'm checking the value of `timeLeft`, too, obviously